# How do I set the legend order by another variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I want to plot the following dataset ordered by ugly_name levels:

```
time <- 1:3
qty <- 1:10
ugly_name <- c("ii" , "aaa"  , "oNe", "iv"  )
nice_name <- c("Two", "Three", "One", "Four")

dt <- data.table(time, qty, ugly_name,nice_name)
dt[, ugly_name := factor(ugly_name, levels = c("oNe", "ii" , "aaa"  , "iv"  ))]
ggplot(dt, aes(x = time, y = qty, fill = ugly_name)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

However I would like to change the `ugly_name` in the legend to the `nice_name`.

The cumbersome way I got it was:

```
dt2 <- dt[, .(ugly_name, nice_name)] %>% unique()
dt2 <- dt2[order(ugly_name)]
dt[, nice_name:= factor(nice_name, levels = dt2$nice_name)]
ggplot(dt, aes(x = time, y = qty, fill = nice_name)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Is there a more straight way to get it done, preferably within ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forcats::fct_reorder lets you apply the ordering of `ugly_name` to `new_name`. In this case I needed to wrap in `as.numeric()`, not entirely sure why.

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = time, y = qty, 
               fill = nice_name %>% forcats::fct_reorder(as.numeric(ugly_name)))) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "category")
```

[image]

Comment: using a new package just for reordering doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: Do you have a suggestion? I tried to factor a variable using the levels of another one without fct_reorder, but I was not able.